# Informatica error =[ERROR('transformation error')]

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am getting the following Informatica error:

> Note: Output column [AGENT_DISPOSTION_CODE] has no default value. Row will be skipped if transformation errors are encountered
>   MAPPING> DBG_21056   column=[PHONE_NUMBER], defaultvalue=[ERROR('transformation error')]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an error, it's only an information that you have a port with a default value set to `ERROR('transformation error')`, so Integration Service will skip the NULL values with an `ERROR` function.

The Designer inserts this expression automatically, when you add a new output port; you can change it. Edit the expression, find the port on the *Ports* tab and check the *Default value* field at the bottom:

[image: output only port]

The `ERROR` function causes the Integration Service to skip a row and issue an error message, which you define.

Answer (score 1):

When running a session on the Verbose Data Mode and if there is no default value specified for output ports in the Mapping, PowerCenter is designed for the warning messages to show up in the session log.

During the column initialization, PowerCenter evaluates the default value specified for each output port in the Mapping and displays the corresponding message. The evaluation code path is the same as for evaluating any other expressions later on during data transformation.

Example
If you specify SIN(1.415) as the default value for an output port, the evaluation on sin(1.415) executes successfully. Upon a successful evaluation, the following message will be displayed:

> MAPPING> DBG_21364 Note: Default value [SIN(1.4)] of output column [output1] will be used if tansformation errors are encountered

However, if the default value is `error('transformation error')`, the following error message will be displayed during evaluation like any real transformation errors:

> MAPPING> TE_7007 Transformation Evaluation Error [<> [ERROR]: transformation error... nl:ERROR(u:'transformation error')]; current row skipped...

Immediately after the evaluation, the following message will be displayed in the session log:

> MAPPING> DBG_21367 Note: Output column [NUM38_37] has no default value. Row will be skipped if transformation errors are encountered